# Troca de src em um Iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

Bom dia amigos.
Estou fazendo uma página onde haverá alguns vídeos do youtube, e com isso terei alguns links que ao serem ativados devem passar o respectivo vídeo para dentro do meu iframe. Porém no processo todo, ao clicar no link do vídeo, ele vai para a tela inteira e não para dentro do iframe. Eis o código:

```
function trocaSrc($a) {
    document.getElemtById("iframe1").src = $a.href;
    return false;
}
```

E os links:

```
<div>
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/18WLEZZVaWY" onClick="return trocaSrc(this);">Video 1</a>
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/0CleeB4bY7U"; onClick="return trocaSrc(this);">Video 2</a>
</div>
```

Não consigo encontrar onde estou errando... Agradeço desde já os amigos que puderem dispor de seu tempo para responder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Erro de sintaxe:

```
document.getElemtById
```

O correto seria:

```
document.getElementById
```

Como o erro acontece antes do `return false;`, o link está direcionando a página para a URL do Youtube que consta no `href`.

> No exemplo abaixo não irá aparecer o vídeo devido a restrições do
>   snippet, mas veja que o link não é redirecionado.

```js
function trocaSrc($a) {
    document.getElementById("iframe1").src = $a.href;
    return false;
}
```

```html
<div>
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/18WLEZZVaWY" onClick="return trocaSrc(this);">Video 1</a>
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/0CleeB4bY7U"; onClick="return trocaSrc(this);">Video 2</a>
</div>
<iframe id="iframe1"></iframe>
```